# Como fazer o select de uma data no formato dd/mm/yyyy no mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Bom dia/tarde/noite

Preciso fazer o select de um campo DO TIPO `DATE` no mysql, os dados estão no formato `yyyy-mm-dd`, preciso que retorne `dd/mm/yyyy`. Existe alguma forma de fazer isso no select?

Já vi soluções com a função `date_format`, porém não obtive sucesso.

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Se poderia colocar a sua SQL ???

Comment: O que exatamente não funcionou? Como você executou, pode colocar na pergunta? Funciona assim:  `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NomeDoCampoDate,'%d/%m/%Y') AS DataFormatada`

Comment: Então o seu campo na tabela não é date? é um varchar?

Comment: Obrigado galera, resolvido. Postei a resposta. Estava fazendo da maneira errada mesmo.

Comment: Normalmente eu costumo converter a data do parâmetro para o padrão do banco e não o contrário

Comment: Errado @diegofm, aqui o campo é do tipo date e não varchar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estava fazendo da maneira errada. Acabei tentando novamente e funcionou.

`SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('campo', '%Y-%m-%d'), '%d/%m/%Y') FROM 'tabela'`